# ASP.NET refresh current page by clicking image

Tags: asp.net

What I am trying to do is to refresh the current .aspx page when the user clicks on an image (phmg.jpg) .

I have the following code and it works:

```
<a href="Currpage.aspx"> 
    <img src="../../images/phmg.jpg" width="900" height="506"/>
</a>
```

I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this in asp.net.
To recap, when the user clicks on "phmg.jpg" I like to refresh the current page.

Note that at the top of the page in the head tag I have the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the page and the content of the page.  If the content is changing often you may run into caching issues.  Where the page refreshes but the content doesn't.

Is it necessary to refresh the entire page?  Is there just a section of the page that can be refresh?  Depending on the complexity of the page, you may want to use update panels to refresh the page.

However, if you are set on refreshing the entire page.  I would add a querystring with a timestamp on the end of the url, so that the browser does a full refresh, and not a cached refresh.

Update: with this method, you don't need the anchor tag, you can just use the image click event.  Please note, this method will remove ALL query strings before reloading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ReloadPage() {
            window.location = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?t=' + new Date().getTime();            
        }
</script>
    <img src="../../images/phmg.jpg" width="900" height="506" onclick="ReloadPage();"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Javalu. With the code that I have, how easy is it to add a querystring. Note that the above code is in .aspx not the code behind.

Comment: Hello, Yes, I nee to refresh the whole page. The page mainly has an image so not that complicated.

Comment: Thanks Javalsu. If I have no caching as I have above, why shouldn't my solution work as well.

Comment: It may work, but image caching should always be handled. As it's dependent on the browser and version.  While it may work for one user, it might not work for all.  It's more of a safety measure more than anything else.  Also account for caching.